# I can't place blocks in modded minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, hosting

I don't know why it is, but I can't place blocks or go to new dimensions in my forge server. I really can't figure out why and need help. I know some people say it might be because my server isn't actually modded, but the mods work in single-player just fine. It only on the server that they don't work.

Comment: are you also rubberbanding? is it only modded blocks or all blocks?\

Comment: im trying to help you but you havent provided enough info

Comment: Is spawn protection on? Try setting yourself as op or move away from spawn. if problem still persists your server console might be spouting some useful information regarding the problem. also sometimes i have a problem on modded where entities stop moving and breaking blocks doesn't drop any items and the best fix so far is just restarting the server.